# Eclipse hangs on Mac when using schema browser and double-clicking on returned results (Force.com)

Tags: eclipse, macos, force.com

I am doing some learning about Force.com and am trying out the schema browser.  I can get results of a query; but when I double-click on a given result Eclipse hangs.

My Mac (8 GB) is running Mac OS X (10.7.4).  Force.com IDE is version 25 and Eclipse is Java EE IDE for Web Developers; Juno Release.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem was that I was running a version of Eclipse that isn't supported (Juno 4.2).  After "uninstalling" Eclipse and installing Force.com IDE as a standalone app my environment is working better.